# Kafka isn't connecting over the internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I've tried setting up Zookeeper on an AWS EC2 Windows 10 instance and then connecting Kafka 2.11-1.1.0 from both the instance and a separate computer.

Within the virtual desktop, I ran:

```
bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties
bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config\server.properties
```

On the other PC, just the second command is run. These are the modified parts of the server.properties file on each computer, on the virtual desktop...

```
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://(AWS private DNS):9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://(AWS public DNS):9092
zookeeper.connect=(AWS private DNS):2181
```

...and on the other computer:

```
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://(local IPv4):9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://(public IPv4):9092
zookeeper.connect=(AWS public DNS):2181
```

Zookeeper and Kafka worked within the virtual PC, but when I tried to start Kafka on the other computer, I got this error:

```
ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
```

Comment: Did you setup the security groups correctly ?

Comment: I opened it to all traffic and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: You're trying to make a cluster from your local machine as well as an EC2 server? If so, of course Zookeeper will timeout

Comment: @cricket_007 Are you talking about the second use of kafka-server-start.bat? Even when I skip that I get the error.

Comment: "the instance and a separate computer"... Are they both in AWS? If not, then that's not a recommended installation of Kafka. Don't cross multiple network boundaries